# Entity framework linq query ThenInclude children entity

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am new to EF Core,  read a number of docs/posts and I am missing something obvious.

I have the following table structure (simplified)

(Parent)
Address

```
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL   
[city_id] [int] NULL
```

(Child)
Parcels

```
[OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AddressId] [int] NULL
```

(Grandchild)
Buildings

```
[OBJECTID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ParcelId] [int] NULL,
```

I used EF generated the models etc.. using Scaffold-DbContext, without issues.

The following works and return the Parcel info associated with the address.

```cs
 public async Task<Address?> GetAddressAsync(int addressId)
 {
 
     return await _geodataContext.Addresses.Include(c => c.Parcels)
                  .Where(c => c.Id == addressId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 }
```

I want to further return the building(s) within the parcel represented by that address. Am I misunderstanding, how the ThenInclude works:

```cs
return await _geodataContext.Addresses
.Include(p => p.Parcels)
    .ThenInclude(b => b.Buildings)
.Where(a => a.Id == addressId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

It doesn't return the building information as part of the Address, only the parcel entity.

Comment: Which EF version are you using? Note that it's better to show the classes (including essential properties, including navigations). Also, please check the generated queries. There should be a correct join with buildings.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your help, i was able to turn on serilog and look at the sql being executed and when I cut/paste those int sql management studio they work as expected. Digging further into my code, It turns out I'm an idiot I was looking for Building in the address entity instead of the parcel entity so address.Parcels.ToList()[0].Building